# Is it safe to drill through metal behind the drywall near the ceiling?

Tags: mounting, curtain-rail

I am trying to mount some brackets for a curtain rod to a wall, very close to the ceiling. Two of the brackets were no problem. When drilling pilot holes for the third, I run into metal. The top hole, I hit metal that is behind the drywall. The bottom hole, I seem to hit metal right beneath the exterior surface of the drywall! I am confused. Is it ok to drill through the metal or should I drill and mount somewhere else?

The wall is an exterior wall. I don't think there's plumbing or electric running right there, and I am not directly above an outlet.

[image: top hole metal behind drywall, bottom hole metal right below surface]

[image: holes in wall near ceiling]

[image: first two brackets, easy, third one, metal]

Comment: It is an odd place for wires/pipes, but finding metal there is odd also.  Would assume it is there for protection of something you do not to drill into, until proven otherwise.

Comment: If you have a strong magnet, like the ones [found in HDD drives](https://makezine.com/article/science/energy/salvage-neodymium-magnets-old-hard-drive/), you can test to see how large the metal object is.  If you hit a nail, like @Ecnerwal suggests, you won't find much more.  But if you find that it's 3.5 inches square, it might be an electrical box and something you don't want to mess with.

Comment: If it's a buried junction box, you actually want to un-bury it and make is accessible. That is a third, and unpleasant but hardly unheard of, option.

Comment: You need to know WHY the metal is there before you drill through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metal at the surface might be a metal corner bead. Or you managed to drill right on top of a nail head, given it's not the hole closer to the corner, and the hole closer to the corner doesn't have that. Easy to avoid those by locating with a magnet *before* you get the drill out.

Metal **behind** is generally a protective plate over plumbing or electric you don't think is there. You may get an unpleasant surprise if you opt to drill through that. Could also be something like a hurricane strap on the framing.